# Drawing a contour that appears on the same location in another image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image for which I found its segmentation. I would like to draw a contour on around the result, and want this contour to also show up in the original image in order for me to see which part has been segmented.

Can I do that in Photoshop?

Thanks.

Comment: Please make an [edit] and include a screenshot of what you're trying to do.   At this time I dont see how we can help you without seeing imagery or knowing what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand that you "found its segmentation" exactly. But I take it that you somehow partitioned it in a way that is meaningful to you. If you want to draw a contour around it you may try the following steps:

1. Make a selection using any tool that fits the bill, polygon lasso tool may work especially well if there are angular corners
2. After the selection is done, add a new blank layer by clicking on the New Layer icon at the bottom of the Layers palette
3. Make sure that the new layer is targeted, click on the new layer  to make sure
4. From the menu, Edit/Stroke and then choose the color and the thickness of the line you wish to draw
5. Click OK

You should have the contour you want.